# Using np.isclose when lambdifying sympy equality conditions in Piecewise

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Consider the following piecewise expression:

```
from sympy import Piecewise, Eq
from sympy.abc import x

expr = Piecewise(
    (1, Eq(x, 0.0)), 
    (x, True)
)
```

Lambdifying this expression with numpy gives the following result:

```
f = lambdify(x, expr, modules="numpy")
print(''.join(inspect.findsource(f)[0]))
# def _lambdifygenerated(x):
#     return select([equal(x, 0),True], [1,x], default=nan)
```

However, this function is designed to be used with a numerical solver, so I have small floating point differences that can give wrong results in the piecewise condition.
**Is it possible to make `lambdify` use `np.isclose` instead of `np.equal` ?**

I've tried adding it to `lambdify`'s `modules` argument, but I don't know what to put as a key as I'm not replacing a function but a relation. This for example doesn't work: `modules={"==": np.isclose}`.

I've also tried creating an `implemented_function`:

```
my_eq = implemented_function('my_eq', lambda x, y: np.isclose(x, y))
expr = Piecewise(
    (1, my_eq(x, 0.0)), 
    (x, True)
)
```

but this gives a `TypeError: Second argument must be a Boolean, not my_eq` when lambdifying, which is understandable if Piecewise expects a boolean relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the lambdify docs

```
def mysin(x):
    print('taking the sin of', x)
    return numpy.sin(x)
f = lambdify(x, sin(x), [{'sin': mysin}, 'numpy'])
f(1)
```

is an example of supplying your own function

### edit

using my function to demonstrate what's happening:

```
def myclose(x,y):
    print('using close', x,y)
    return np.isclose(x,y)

In [302]: f = lambdify(x, expr, modules=[ "numpy"])
     ...: print(''.join(inspect.findsource(f)[0]))
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return select([equal(x, 0),True], [1,x], default=nan)
    
In [303]: f1 = lambdify(x, expr, modules=[{'equal':myclose}, "numpy"])
     ...: print(''.join(inspect.findsource(f)[0]))
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return select([equal(x, 0),True], [1,x], default=nan)
```

The substitution does not show  up in the displayed code, but when run we see a difference:

```
In [304]: f(np.arange(3)-1e-10)
Out[304]: array([-1.e-10,  1.e+00,  2.e+00])

In [305]: f1(np.arange(3)-1e-10)
using close [-1.e-10  1.e+00  2.e+00] 0
Out[305]: array([1., 1., 2.])
```

Comment: I had done exactly that but didn't notice it actually changed something, because the displayed function name doesn't match. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your goal is to create a custom numpy printer, override the `_print_Relational` method to inform the printer to use `isequal`, and give the printer to `lambdify`:

```py
class MyNumPyPrinter(NumPyPrinter):
    def _print_Relational(self, expr):
        "Relational printer for Equality and Unequality"
        op = {
            '==' :'isclose',
            '!=' :'not_equal',
            '<'  :'less',
            '<=' :'less_equal',
            '>'  :'greater',
            '>=' :'greater_equal',
        }
        if expr.rel_op in op:
            lhs = self._print(expr.lhs)
            rhs = self._print(expr.rhs)
            return '{op}({lhs}, {rhs})'.format(op=self._module_format(self._module + '.'+op[expr.rel_op]),
                                               lhs=lhs, rhs=rhs)
        return super()._print_Relational(expr)
    
f = lambdify(x, expr, printer=MyNumPyPrinter)
f(1e-12)
# out: array(1.)
```

Comment: Although I prefer to use the `modules` parameter, this is good to know!